# How to convert fraction to float in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert `"1 1/2"` in JavaScript so that when I say print x (where `x = "1 1/2"`) it returns `1.5`.

Currently while using the following code

```
var value = $('#ingredients-1-quantity').val();
var fraction = Number(value);
if(isNaN(fraction)) {
 if(hasFraction = parseFrac(value)) {
  $('#ingredients-1-quantity-hidden').val(hasFraction);
 }
 else {
  $('#ingredients-1-quantity').val('');
  $('#ingredients-1-quantity-hidden').val('');
 }
}

function parseFrac(frac) {
 frac = frac.split(/ ?(\d+)\/(\d+)/);
 if(!isNaN(parseInt(frac[2])))
   return Math.round(frac[0] * 1 + frac[1] / frac[2], 3);
 else
   return false;
}
```

Also the code should take care of integer and float values. For example if I say print `1` OR print `1.5` it will return as it is.

I am elaborating more. I have a Ingredient form where I am providing text-field, where user will provide Quantity of food under it. This can be float, integer or fraction.

For example

1. **1/2** Teaspoon of Salt
2. **1 1/2** Teaspoon of Chilli Powder
3. **2.5** Teaspoon of garlic powder
4. **2** Teaspoon of cream-style horseradish

if user is providing value in float or integer that is fine but if user is providing value in fraction than I have convert it into float.

On the view page it is fine to show the quantity as it is (entered by user) but for internal use I have to keep the fraction as float.

I got this working with the above code. Thanks @Rocket for the idea

Comment: `1/2` will already be converted to `0.5`, what are you doing? `parseFloat()` should convert string to number safer than `eval()`. Or just multiply by 1 and let JS do typecasting for you.

Comment: `var x = 1/2; alert(x); // alerts 0.5`

Comment: It seems like this is the default behavior for JS, since there is not a strict distinction between types (such as float and integer).

Comment: I assume you have the string `"1/2"`?

Comment: There is no  `print` statement anyways :)

Comment: @Rocket: yes user is entering value in textfield

Comment: @Ivan: I tried eval but it is not handling the case where the value is `1 1/2`

Comment: How can you have `-2 Teaspoon`?

Comment: @Roket: Sorry that mistakenly got written I fixed it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed.  I have a function that I use for this exact purpose:  [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeric-quantity) / [GitHub](https://github.com/jakeboone02/numeric-quantity/blob/master/index.js).  Related SO q&a [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29171092/765987).

Comment: I think what you want is this: https://github.com/peterolson/BigRational.js

Comment: The simplest way is using a library like Fraction.js https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js

Answer (score 4):

You can use `eval` (if you can trust where the string is coming from).

```
console.log(eval('1/2')); // 0.5
console.log(eval('1.5')); // 1.5
```

Or, you can split the string on the `/`.

```
var x = '1/2';

var y = x.split('/');
if(y.length > 1){
    console.log(y[0] / y[1]);
}
else{
    console.log(y[0]);
}
```

**UPDATE**: Handling mixed numbers, such as `1 1/2` will take a little more parsing.  Besides splitting on the `/`, we need to split on the space.

```
var x = '1 1/2';

var y = x.split(' ');
if(y.length > 1){
    var z = y[1].split('/');
    console.log(+y[0] + (z[0] / z[1]));
}
else{
    var z = y[0].split('/');
    if(z.length > 1){
        console.log(z[0] / z[1]);
    }
    else{
        console.log(z[0]);
    }
}​
```

Comment: @Roket: it is not working in case of `1 1/2`