# Double.TryParse doesn't allow to use divisions (fractions) as input

Tags: c#

I have created a method that splits a string a^b and converts a and b to doubles. However, if I input the value of either a or b using a fraction (for example 3/5 instead of 0.6) the method doesn't work; it only allows me to input it like 0.6. Why is this, and is it possible to fix it?

The code is shown below:

```
public static double Coefficient()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] items = input.Split('^');

        if (items.Length == 1)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(items[0], out double A))
                return A; 
        }

        else if (items.Length == 2)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(items[0], out double A) &
                double.TryParse(items[1], out double B))
                return Math.Pow(A, B); 
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease follow the specified input form.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're splitting on the `^` character, and since `"4/2"` doesn't contain that character, you get that string back, and then you pass it to `double.TryParse`.

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to parse the string `"4/2"` as if it were a string representing a floating point number? Due to the fact that it isn't, that's not going to work. If you want to evaluate expressions, you'll need to use some kind of expression evaluator library. NCalc is one example.

Comment: Made a mistake in the title, the method converts strings to doubles

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a logical AND (||) not a bitwise and (&)?

Comment: @user7733611 `||` is `or`, not `and`; you're thinking of `&&`. In C#, [bitwise `&` works like logical `and` on boolean values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator). He's fine. But yes, I wouldn't have used that operator either, if only because the nuns who taught me ANSI C thrashed me savagely. In fairness, I was a feral child.

Comment: @Anders check my answer

Comment: `3/5` is fraction but floating point values can't be natively represented that way in C#. If you need just those - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903621/convert-a-text-fraction-to-a-decimal is the answer (duplicate), if you want to actually parse math expression - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972854/parse-math-expression

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse expressions with methods that only know how to handle specifically formatted numbers as inputs. You need to either [write an equation parser](https://medium.com/@CantabileApp/writing-a-simple-math-expression-engine-in-c-d414de18d4ce) or split your inputs appropriately. You are already doing this by splitting `^` - you can do the same with `/`.

In fact, there are libraries [that already do this](http://mathparser.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm really new and I don't really understand how to use these libraries at all though.