# Return 1/2 for input values that are less than 0.05 - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to return `1/2` for all the input values that are `<0.05`. (Don't bother with the math. I just want to return `1/2` for all the values that are `<0.05`).

Here is the snippet that I'm working on:

```js
function simpler(whole, x, y) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return whole;
  } else if (x == 1 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 2 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 3 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 3 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 4 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 2 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 5 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 2 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 6 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 3 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 7 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 7 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 8 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 4 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 9 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 9 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else {
    return whole + '<sup>' + x + '</sup>/<sub>' + y + '</sub>';
  }
}

function Fraction() {}
Fraction.prototype.convert = function(x, improper) {
  improper = improper || false;
  var abs = Math.abs(x);
  this.sign = x / abs;
  x = abs;
  var stack = 0;
  this.whole = !improper ? Math.floor(x) : 0;
  var fractional = !improper ? x - this.whole : abs;

  function recurs(x) {
    stack++;
    var intgr = Math.floor(x);
    var dec = (x - intgr);
    if (dec < 0.0019 || stack > 20) return [intgr, 1];
    var num = recurs(1 / dec);
    return [intgr * num[0] + num[1], num[0]]
  }
  var t = recurs(fractional);
  this.numerator = t[0];
  this.denominator = t[1];
}

Fraction.prototype.toString = function() {
  var l = this.sign.toString().length;
  var sign = l === 2 ? '-' : '';
  var whole = this.whole !== 0 ? this.sign * this.whole + ' ' : sign;
  return simpler(whole, this.numerator, this.denominator);

}

function f() {
  var text = $('#text').val();
  var roundUp = 0.4;
  var digit = (text * 1).toFixed(1);
  var frac = new Fraction()
  frac.convert(digit, false)
  $('#result').html(frac.toString());
}

$('#text').on('change', function() {
  f();
});

f();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="0.04" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Here in the example, I've used `toFixed(1)` to keep only one decimal of the input. As a result, if the input value is `<0.05` it returns nothing. But I want to return `1/2` instead.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're trying to do (1/2 !== 0.05 and your example converts 0.25 into 2/5 for example) but you may benefit from looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368529/jquery-convert-results-of-decimal-into-fractions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want the output value to be `1/2` for inputs `<0.05` no matter what the actual math is. @Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something simple like: (I used in the snippet)

```
if ( '' === whole && 0 == x & 1 == y ) {
  return '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 2 + '</sub>';
}
```

or maybe just:

```
if ( '' === whole ) {
  return '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 2 + '</sub>';
}
```

```js
function simpler(whole, x, y) {
  if ( '' === whole && 0 == x & 1 == y ) {
    // If the input value is < 0.05, `whole` is an empty string with `x` = 0 and `y` = 1
    return '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 2 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 0) {
    return whole;
  } else if (x == 1 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 2 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 3 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 3 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 4 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 2 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 5 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 2 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 6 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 3 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 7 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 7 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 8 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 4 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 9 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 9 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else {
    return whole + '<sup>' + x + '</sup>/<sub>' + y + '</sub>';
  }
}

function Fraction() {}
Fraction.prototype.convert = function(x, improper) {
  improper = improper || false;
  var abs = Math.abs(x);
  this.sign = x / abs;
  x = abs;
  var stack = 0;
  this.whole = !improper ? Math.floor(x) : 0;
  var fractional = !improper ? x - this.whole : abs;

  function recurs(x) {
    stack++;
    var intgr = Math.floor(x);
    var dec = (x - intgr);
    if (dec < 0.0019 || stack > 20) return [intgr, 1];
    var num = recurs(1 / dec);
    return [intgr * num[0] + num[1], num[0]]
  }
  var t = recurs(fractional);
  this.numerator = t[0];
  this.denominator = t[1];
}

Fraction.prototype.toString = function() {
  var l = this.sign.toString().length;
  var sign = l === 2 ? '-' : '';
  var whole = this.whole !== 0 ? this.sign * this.whole + ' ' : sign;
  return simpler(whole, this.numerator, this.denominator);

}

function f() {
  var text = $('#text').val();
  var roundUp = 0.4;
  var digit = (text * 1).toFixed(1);
  var frac = new Fraction()
  frac.convert(digit, false)
  $('#result').html(frac.toString());
}

$('#text').on('change', function() {
  f();
});

f();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="0.04" />
<div id="result"></div>
0 or 0.00 would also return &frac12;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is the perfect way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got everything right that you want to achieve. But what about this:

Basically I just define a fix *template* (`var low_num_template`) and assign this to your `#result` box when the value is **below 0.05** (assuming that you only have numbers in this input. If there are alphabetical characters you would have to check for this first before using `parseFloat()` to prevent an error).

Did I get you right with this?

```js
function simpler(whole, x, y) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return whole;
  } else if (x == 1 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 2 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 3 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 3 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 4 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 2 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 5 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 2 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 6 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 3 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 7 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 7 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 8 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 4 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 9 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 9 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else {
    return whole + '<sup>' + x + '</sup>/<sub>' + y + '</sub>';
  }
}

function Fraction() {}
Fraction.prototype.convert = function(x, improper) {
  improper = improper || false;
  var abs = Math.abs(x);
  this.sign = x / abs;
  x = abs;
  var stack = 0;
  this.whole = !improper ? Math.floor(x) : 0;
  var fractional = !improper ? x - this.whole : abs;

  function recurs(x) {
    stack++;
    var intgr = Math.floor(x);
    var dec = (x - intgr);
    if (dec < 0.0019 || stack > 20) return [intgr, 1];
    var num = recurs(1 / dec);
    return [intgr * num[0] + num[1], num[0]]
  }
  var t = recurs(fractional);
  this.numerator = t[0];
  this.denominator = t[1];
}

Fraction.prototype.toString = function() {
  var l = this.sign.toString().length;
  var sign = l === 2 ? '-' : '';
  var whole = this.whole !== 0 ? this.sign * this.whole + ' ' : sign;
  return simpler(whole, this.numerator, this.denominator);

}

function f() {
  var text = $('#text').val();
  text = parseFloat(text);
  var roundUp = 0.4;
  var digit = (text * 1).toFixed(1);
  var frac = new Fraction()
  frac.convert(digit, false)
  
  var low_num_template = '<sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>';
  $('#result').html((text < 0.05) ? low_num_template : frac.toString());
  
}

$('#text').on('change', function() {
  f();
});

f();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="0.04" />
<div id="result">asdasd</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but wouldn't it be cleaner if we could use some logic in the `function simpler`, maybe something like, `if (x == 0 && y == 0 && whole == 0)` ... `return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 2 + '</sub>'` ... or something like this that actually works?

Answer (score -1):

```js
function simpler(whole, x, y) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return whole;
  } else if (x == 1 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 2 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 3 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 3 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 4 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 2 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 5 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 2 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 6 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 3 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 7 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 7 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 8 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 4 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 9 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 9 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 10 + '</sub>'
  } else {
    return whole + '<sup>' + x + '</sup>/<sub>' + y + '</sub>';
  }
}

function Fraction() {}
Fraction.prototype.convert = function(x, improper) {
  improper = improper || false;
  var abs = Math.abs(x);
  this.sign = x / abs;
  x = abs;
  var stack = 0;
  this.whole = !improper ? Math.floor(x) : 0;
  var fractional = !improper ? x - this.whole : abs;

  function recurs(x) {
    stack++;
    var intgr = Math.floor(x);
    var dec = (x - intgr);
    if (dec < 0.0019 || stack > 20) return [intgr, 1];
    var num = recurs(1 / dec);
    return [intgr * num[0] + num[1], num[0]]
  }
  var t = recurs(fractional);
  this.numerator = t[0];
  this.denominator = t[1];
}

Fraction.prototype.toString = function() {
  var l = this.sign.toString().length;
  var sign = l === 2 ? '-' : '';
  var whole = this.whole !== 0 ? this.sign * this.whole + ' ' : sign;
  return simpler(whole, this.numerator, this.denominator);

}

function f() {
  var text = $('#text').val();
  var roundUp = 0.4;
  var digit = (text * 1).toFixed(1);
  var frac = new Fraction()
  frac.convert(digit, false)
  if(parseInt(text)<0.05){
      $('#result').html("1/2");
   }
 else{
  $('#result').html(frac.toString());}
  }

$('#text').on('change', function() {
  f();
});

f();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="0.04" />
<div id="result"></div>
```